# Why does '/./,/^$/!d' have any effect in sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

I came upon an example of sed simulating `cat -s`, which will replace two or more empty lines by one empty line.

The command is below

```
echo -e "\n-------------\nline1\n\nline2\nline3\n\n\nline4\n\n\n\nlast line\n-------------" | sed '1s/^$//p;/./,/^$/!d'
```

I understand the sed part has two parts. The first one, `'1s/^$//p'` will take place on first line and will just print nothing to the first line of it's empty. Ok, that part I get it.

Now, for the second part, `'/./,/^$/!d'`, it will delete the line if it does not match `/./`, any single character or `/^$/` empty line. That covers pretty much anything, no? How come an empty line after another empty line is matched by that?

Comment: Please try to write your question titles to be *specific to the individual question*. Someone who's trying to figure out if we already have a Q&A entry that helps them and has 100 search results that all have the title "Why doesn't this sed expression work the way I expect?" (or some analog to the same) would have to click through into each one to see if the expression covered in that question is analogous to the one they're asking about, and thus if that answer will help them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sed manual says this:

> Appending the '!' character to the end of an address specification
>   (before the command letter) negates the sense of the match.

The sed command `/./,/^$/!d` is therefore "delete rows that are *not* in a range defined by a line with any character until and including one blank line". So it *will* delete rows that are not in this kind of range.

```
  1 -------------
  2 line1
  3 
  4 line2
  5 line3
  6 
  7 
  8 line4
  9 
 10 
 11 
 12 last line
 13 -------------
 14
```

The first range is lines 1-3.
The second range is lines 4-6.
The next range is lines 8-9.
The last range is lines 12-14.

Lines 7 and 10-11 do not fall into any of the matched ranges, so they are affected by the `!` modifier, and they get deleted.

I can think of ways to do this in other programming languages that would be more clear, but if all you've got is `sed` then this is an effective way to reduce redundant blank lines.

Comment: Ahhhhhh right. /<something>/,/<something else>/ is a range. Not two separate values. Thank you for reminding me that.